# Dynamically add imageView to layout

Tags: android, imageview, android-linearlayout, dynamically-generated

Every time I go to add an Image view to my Linear Layout dynamically I get a null pointer exception.

```
LinearLayout tables = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.table);

        for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
            ImageView image = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
            try{
                int imgID = getResources().getIdentifier(data[i], "drawable", "package");
                image.setImageResource(imgID);

            }catch(Exception e){
                int imgID = getResources().getIdentifier("nia", "drawable", "package");
                image.setImageResource(imgID);
            }               
            tables.addView(image); //NULL POINTER THROWN HERE
        }
```

When I debug, the imgID has a value, so I know its working.  I just don't understand why its null if

Comment: `tables` is null, you probably hadven't `setContentView` or R.id.table isn't in that view

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is the line that causes the Null Pointer Exception:

```
tables.addView(image);
```

Then `tables` is null, simply findViewById() did not find any View with the id `R.id.table` in the current layout being displayed.

(If you want help figuring out why `tables` is null, please post the layout which you pass to `setContentView()`)

**Added from comments**

Here is a general way to create a PopupWindow. This uses a LayoutInflator to inflate the layout so that we can access it to dynamically add elements to the layout. (Notice that we scope find to `popupLayout.findViewById(...)`):

```
public class Example extends Activity {
    private PopupWindow popupWindow;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
        text.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                createPopup(view);
            }
        });
    }

    public void createPopup(View view) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);  
        View popupLayout = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup, null);  
        // Customize popup's layout here

        Button dismissButton = (Button) popupLayout.findViewById(R.id.dismiss);
        dismissButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                popupWindow.dismiss();
            }
        });

        popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupLayout, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        popupWindow.showAtLocation(view, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

Understand that the root element in `popup.xml` should have a `background` attribute defined otherwise the window is transparent by default.

Comment: LinearLayout tables = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.table);

Comment: Yes, but `findViewById(R.id.table)` returns null... therefor `tables` is null.

Comment: Well I made an xml file with a LinearLayout with an id of table so I dont understand why it would be null.

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/table"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    

</LinearLayout>

Comment: No trouble, what is this file named and where do you pass it to setContentView() in your Activity?

Comment: Comments only have limited formatting options... You can edit the XML into your question if you want. But it's short enough to not be confusing.

Comment: file is name table.xml and it is sent to a popup window instead of being sent to a contentVuew

Comment: If you want to search the layout of your popup window (call it `window`) then use `window.findViewById(R.id.table)`.

Comment: I dont quite understand...  Im making the linear layout so that I can addimages to it and then open it in a pop up window

Comment: findViewById() only returns Views that are _currently_ being displayed... You can create the window and _then_ edit the layout faster than the user can see any changes. But you cannot edit a layout _before_ it is displayed like this.

Comment: Ohhhhhhhh I think I understand. So pop it up, then add pictures?

Comment: Could you submit an answer with the code formatted around properly?  I tried doing it myself and it didnt work I dont have time right now to screw with it.  Ill accept it as the correct answer tomorrow when I log on.

Comment: Thanks for all the help.  This helped a lot and in my code I realized the popup View needed to be instantiated first, then when I created my linear layout I needed to say "popupView.findViewById(R.layout.tables)". That helped with the whole "findViewById only looks at your current context", thakns for the help

Answer (score 3):

to check if there is a problem with your XML layout you can try to define the layout programmatically

```
        LinearLayout tables = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());

        for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
            ImageView image = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
            try{
                int imgID = getResources().getIdentifier(data[i], "drawable", "package");
                image.setImageResource(imgID);

            }catch(Exception e){
                int imgID = getResources().getIdentifier("nia", "drawable", "package");
                image.setImageResource(imgID);
            }               
            tables.addView(image); 
        }
```

And adds this view like a ContentView

```
        setContentView(tables);
```